# Mailkit is connecting via TLS 1.0 while TLS 1.2 protocol is enabled on Nginx

Tags: .net, nginx, ssl, tls1.2, mailkit

I am using MailKit library to send emails. However the below error keeps on showing

> MailKit.Security.SslHandshakeException: An error occurred while attempting to establish an SSL or TLS connection.

I am using Nginx web server and have changed ssl protocols to support TLS 1.2 and TLS 1.3 and checked that both protocols are enabled via SSLLabs test. However on the smtp client logs (which supports TLS 1.2) it shows that the handshake has been done via TLS 1.0 as in this snapshot

[image]

Comment: only allow TLS 1.2 and 1.3 in Nginx by setting `ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;` in the configuration

Comment: I did so but how to know why on the client it is still showing TLS 1.0

Comment: Add the following line of code to your program, right before calling `client.Connect()`: `Console.WriteLine ("client.SslProtocols = {0}", client.SslProtocols);` What is the result?

Comment: Set SslProtocols to Tls12 or Tls13. http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/P_MailKit_MailService_SslProtocols.htm https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols?view=net-5.0

Comment: @jstedfast The result shows client.SslProtocols = Tls12

Comment: SSL in MailKit is handled by the framework SslStream, so if it's using the wrong SSL protocol, I guess that's an issue you'll need to report to Microsoft.

Comment: What SSL protocols I should have running on Nginx to prevent conflict?